# H5F.flush() removed from HDF5DotNet 1.8.7?

Tags: .net, flush, hdf5

I recently upgraded my Hdf5DotNet wrapper library from 1.8.6 to 1.8.7 and noticed that the H5F.flush() method was removed.  Anyone know the reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any indication as to why this was removed - from what I gather it is still present in the native DLL and in the C-style header - the reference manual doesn't mark it as deprecated or similar.

V 1.8.7 seems to have some "special effects" like imbalancing the stack (due to some inconsistency with calling conventions) when called from managed code (for example the open function)... I didn't try it but adding back `H5F.flush` into the .NET wrapper is rather easy... I would suggest to do it IF you really need it... IF this creates even bigger problem than an imbalanced stack this can always be overcome by impelementing a "native proxy DLL" with the correct calling conventions and using that from the .NET wrapper.

**EDIT - as per comments:**

The available .NET wrappers seem rather weak, sometime incomplete etc. - Since the source is available implementing a .NET wrapper seems a doable task.

As a starting point see:

- http://hdf5.net/downloads/HDF5DotNet-src.zip
- http://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/hdf5-1.8.7/src/

Comment: We're looking at HDF5 to replace a proprietary flat file database, but find the .Net wrappers to be weak. We'll likely end up writing a proper OO-wrapper due to the number of problems like this we've encountered.